# How to call vue method from a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to call a vue method from javascript function but can't make it work. The method I am trying to call is `app.onChangePlant(val)` It turns out that the value is not called.

Is it because of the vue is not yet available when I declared the javascript function?

This is the error I am receiving

```
plant-consumer:222 Uncaught TypeError: app.onChangePlant is not a function
    at onChangePlantSelect (plant-consumer:222)
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (plant-consumer:399)
    at Object.trigger (app.js:14973)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (app.js:15045)
    at Function.each (app.js:6863)
    at jQuery.fn.init.ea
```

Code:

```
<script type="module" defer>
    const setting = {
        url: {
            findUsage: "{{ route('admin.plant-consumer.find-usage') }}",
            usageCsvDownload: "{{ route('admin.plant-consumer.usage-csv-download') }}",
        },
        date: {
            date_default: moment("{{ $defaultDate }}", 'YYYY/MM/DD').toDate()
        }
    };
    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            url: setting.url,
            plantId: '',
            isLoading: false,
            rangeFilter: 'daily',
            byMonth: false,
            csvDownloadUrl: '',
            date: setting.date.date_default,
            month: setting.date.date_default,
            // datepicker用設定
            DatePickerFormat: 'yyyy/MM/dd',
            MonthPickerFormat: 'yyyy/MM',
            disabledDates: {
                from: new Date()
            },
            ja_vdp: vdp_translation_ja.js
        },
        components: {
            'vuejs-datepicker': vuejsDatepicker
        },
        watch: {
            rangeFilter: function () {
                this.byMonth = this.rangeFilter === 'monthly';
                this.getData(1);
            },
        },
        methods: {
            onChangePlant: function(event) {
                this.plantId = event.target.value;
                this.getData(1);
            },
            onChangeDate: function () {
                this.getData(1);
            },
            onChangeMonth: function () {
                this.getData(1);
            },
            getData: function(page) {
                let that = this;
                let date = that.date;
                that.isLoading = true;
                that.csvDownloadUrl = '';
                if (that.byMonth) {
                    date = that.month;
                }
                if(that.plantId && ((date)))
                {
                    let data = {
                        plant : that.plantId,
                        date : that.formatDateForRequest(date),
                        byMonth: that.byMonth,
                        page : page,
                    };
                    let url = that.url.usageCsvDownload
                            + '?plant=' + data.plant
                            + '&date=' + data.date
                            + '&byMonth=' + data.byMonth;

                    // console.log(url);
                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: that.url.findUsage,
                        type: "get",
                        datatype: "html",
                        data: data,
                        cache: false
                    }).done(function(data){
                        $("#consumer_table_generate").empty().html(data);
                        that.csvDownloadUrl = url;
                    }).fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                        alert('No response from server');
                    }).always(function() {
                        that.isLoading = false;
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#consumer_ratio_body").empty();
                    that.isLoading = false;
                }
            }
        },
        mounted: function () {
            let vueObj = this;

            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $(document).on('click', '.pagination a', function(event)
            {
                event.preventDefault();

                let $this = $(this);
                $('#consumer_table_generate li').removeClass('active');
                $this.parent('li').addClass('active');

                var page = $this.attr('href').split('page=')[1];

                vueObj.getData(page);
            });
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

    });

</script>

<script>
    function onChangePlantSelect(val) {
        console.log(val);
        app.onChangePlant(val);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Why not just move your function inside of the other script tag, if you're worried about the `defer` or something messing with it?

Comment: Module scripts are deferred by default. Your `defer` attribute has no effect, but still your module script code will run after the page is parsed. Unable to say it that's what's causing your problem because the problem description is not very clear and you don't provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

```
const App = {
        data: {
            url: setting.url,
            plantId: '',
            isLoading: false,
            rangeFilter: 'daily',
            byMonth: false,
            csvDownloadUrl: '',
            date: setting.date.date_default,
            month: setting.date.date_default,
            // datepicker用設定
            DatePickerFormat: 'yyyy/MM/dd',
            MonthPickerFormat: 'yyyy/MM',
            disabledDates: {
                from: new Date()
            },
            ja_vdp: vdp_translation_ja.js
        },
        components: {
            'vuejs-datepicker': vuejsDatepicker
        },
        watch: {
            rangeFilter: function () {
                this.byMonth = this.rangeFilter === 'monthly';
                this.getData(1);
            },
        },
        methods: {
            onChangePlant: function(event) {
                this.plantId = event.target.value;
                this.getData(1);
            },
            onChangeDate: function () {
                this.getData(1);
            },
            onChangeMonth: function () {
                this.getData(1);
            },
            getData: function(page) {
                let that = this;
                let date = that.date;
                that.isLoading = true;
                that.csvDownloadUrl = '';
                if (that.byMonth) {
                    date = that.month;
                }
                if(that.plantId && ((date)))
                {
                    let data = {
                        plant : that.plantId,
                        date : that.formatDateForRequest(date),
                        byMonth: that.byMonth,
                        page : page,
                    };
                    let url = that.url.usageCsvDownload
                            + '?plant=' + data.plant
                            + '&date=' + data.date
                            + '&byMonth=' + data.byMonth;

                    // console.log(url);
                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: that.url.findUsage,
                        type: "get",
                        datatype: "html",
                        data: data,
                        cache: false
                    }).done(function(data){
                        $("#consumer_table_generate").empty().html(data);
                        that.csvDownloadUrl = url;
                    }).fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                        alert('No response from server');
                    }).always(function() {
                        that.isLoading = false;
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#consumer_ratio_body").empty();
                    that.isLoading = false;
                }
            }
        },
        mounted: function () {
            let vueObj = this;

            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $(document).on('click', '.pagination a', function(event)
            {
                event.preventDefault();

                let $this = $(this);
                $('#consumer_table_generate li').removeClass('active');
                $this.parent('li').addClass('active');

                var page = $this.attr('href').split('page=')[1];

                vueObj.getData(page);
            });
        }
    }
const app = Vue.createApp(App)

const vm = app.mount('#blog-posts-demo')

vm.remove(123456)
```

//this way you guarantee the app is properly mounted, by the time you call

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why would you like to do that but if it's neccessary you can try to use window eventlisteners:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

In your component you can add an eventlistener that call your method, in js script tage you can fire an event, if your component ready it will call the method.

I never did this before it's just a theory :)

edit: I tried it, but your component is not mounted when you want to fire the event in script tag